# Javascript: getting data from a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The basics:  I have an HTML table. I want to add rows to the table without reloading the page.  I've created a servlet that returns values I want to add to the table whenever the "add" button is clicked.

The problem: I can dynamically add rows to the table just fine.  The problem is getting the data from the servlet in.  The servlet is very simple. Send it three values and it returns a JSON with the values for the new row.  I've tested and it works just fine.  The problem is the variables I use to hold the values don't pass beyond the function I have setup in $.getJSON().  I don't have a lot of experience with javascript so I'm not exactly sure of the precedence of variable declarations, but one thing is certain, my variables don't hold their value once the inner function is done. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
function addPerson()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("newperson");
    var personid = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var roleid = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var r = document.getElementById("newrole");
    var roleid = r.options[r.selectedIndex].value;
    var o = document.getElementById("thisorganizationid");
    var orgid = o.options[o.selectedIndex].value;

    var personName = "";
    var orgName = "";
    var roleName = "";

    $.getJSON("GetPersonRole",{
        personid: personid,
        roleid: roleid,
        orgid: orgid,
      }, function(json) {
          personName = json.Person;
          orgName = json.Organization;
          roleName = json.Role;

          alert('person: ' + personName + '  role: ' + roleName); //They all display properly here
      });

    var table = document.getElementById("PersonTable");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = orgName;

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = personName;

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell3.innerHTML = roleName;

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell4.innerHTML = "adding";

    document.getElementById('addingPerson').innerHTML = addString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is an asynchronous function. If you're not sure what that means, I suggest reading a tutorial on asynchronous JS programming.

The simple answer to your question is this: You're attempting to assign the values of your variables to your DOM elements before the [`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method has completed. Here's a quick fix (see comments for further explanation):

```
...

$.getJSON("GetPersonRole",{
        personid: personid,
        roleid: roleid,
        orgid: orgid,
      }, function(json) { //Executes when the asynchronous call is complete
          personName = json.Person;
          orgName = json.Organization;
          roleName = json.Role;

          UpdateMyPage(personName, orgName, roleName);
});

//Most likely will execute before the asynchronous call is complete
alert("HERE");

function UpdateMyPage(personName, orgName, roleName) {
    var table = document.getElementById("PersonTable");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = orgName;

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = personName;

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell3.innerHTML = roleName;

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell4.innerHTML = "adding";

    document.getElementById('addingPerson').innerHTML = addString;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your callback function:

```
    $.getJSON("GetPersonRole",{
        personid: personid,
        roleid: roleid,
        orgid: orgid,
      }, function(json) {
          personName = json.Person;
          orgName = json.Organization;
          roleName = json.Role;

          alert('person: ' + personName + '  role: ' + roleName); //They all display properly here
 });
```

Executes when the AJAX call is returned.  Meaning that your variables are not being set with the new values until after they have already been added to the table.

Your code should be something like this:

```
function addPerson()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("newperson");
    var personid = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var roleid = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var r = document.getElementById("newrole");
    var roleid = r.options[r.selectedIndex].value;
    var o = document.getElementById("thisorganizationid");
    var orgid = o.options[o.selectedIndex].value;

    var personName = "";
    var orgName = "";
    var roleName = "";

    $.getJSON("GetPersonRole",{
        personid: personid,
        roleid: roleid,
        orgid: orgid,
      }, function(json) {
          personName = json.Person;
          orgName = json.Organization;
          roleName = json.Role;

          alert('person: ' + personName + '  role: ' + roleName); //They all display properly here

          var table = document.getElementById("PersonTable");
          var rowCount = table.rows.length;
          var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          cell1.innerHTML = orgName;

          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
          cell2.innerHTML = personName;

          var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
          cell3.innerHTML = roleName;

          var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
          cell4.innerHTML = "adding";

          document.getElementById('addingPerson').innerHTML = addString;
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You're absolutely right. I see what I did wrong now. Including the remaining code in getJSON causes that whole block to execute in kind.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the row is added before the values are returned by the server. I would make and addRow() function and call it on success:

```
function addRow(json){
    // include all code after the getJSON method above...
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = json.Organization;

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = json.Person;

    // etc...
}
```

Then you'd need to do:

```
$.getJSON("GetPersonRole",{
    personid: personid,
    roleid: roleid,
    orgid: orgid,
  }, addRow);
```

Answer (score -5):

Your variables are defined within the scope of the function.  If you defined them globally, like so, you should be able to access them elsewhere:

```
var personName = "";
var orgName = "";
var roleName = "";
function addPerson()
    {
        ...

etc...
```

Comment: He is using them within the function too, the formatting was a little messed up which made it look like the addPerson function had already ended.

Comment: That isn't going to fix it.  If you look, you will see that the table is updated before the AJAX callback executes.